# HttpContext IP Problem

Tags: c#, httpcontext, ipv6, ipv4

I have a problem when I use `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress`, some times returns "192.168.0.17" (IPv4) and some times returns "fe80::99be:a05d:7938:1c30%8" (IPv6), calling from the same computer and navigator.

What I do to return always IPv4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution that somebody hacked up. Can't say if it'll work, tho =)

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30078410/request-object.aspx

Comment: Beat me with a virtually identical solution by mere seconds. +1

Comment: @md5sum: well the good news, then, is none of us deserves the creds for the actual code ;)

Comment: yup, dead link - which is why SO recommends posting the answer, not just a link to the answer. :/

Comment: Correct. Alas I cannot delete an accepted answer. As the comments by Nathan points out, though, this was the same solution as in this answer

Answer (score 3):

Check out this post on 4GuysFromRolla and see if it helps at all. I think this is the information you're looking for.

https://web.archive.org/web/20201028122055/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/071807-1.aspx

~md5sum~

```
 public static string GetIP4Address()
  {
    string IP4Address = String.Empty;

    foreach (IPAddress IPA in Dns.GetHostAddresses(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress))
    {
      if (IPA.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
      {
        IP4Address = IPA.ToString();
        break;
      }
    }

    if (IP4Address != String.Empty)
    {
      return IP4Address;
    }

    foreach (IPAddress IPA in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
    {
      if (IPA.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
      {
        IP4Address = IPA.ToString();
        break;
      }
    }

    return IP4Address;
  }
```